# Images on SSL App Engine

Tags: image, google-app-engine, ssl, https, google-cloud-storage

I have an application on Google App Engine.   I used to store images within Ndb blobs, and serve them from GAE.   Then all this relatively static seemed to put needless load on the application, and I switched to storing all images (including user-uploaded) within a GCS bucket, made publicly available through http://static.mysite.com, and served directly from there.

This is working great.   Until I consider switching the application to SSL.

Setting up SSL for my GAE application went OK, but then I get security warnings because images are not served through SSL.   So I need an SSL access to my GCS images, but GCS does not support SSL, and I see no plans for it in the future.

What are the options ?  Storing images in GCS seems to be the recommended choice, and going SSL is now recommended for most websites, but the two seem to be incompatible.

I see Google CDN could be one approach that would (maybe) support SSL, but it's kind of overkill in my case.

Comment: I just add `https://` before the public url of the image stored in GCS and it works. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Indeed, it would work.  I should have added that I would rather have my images served on something like static.mysite.com, than storage.googleapis.com/...,  i.e. not exposing googleapis.   But I might have to give up on this requirement.

Comment: You can setup your app engine app to work as a proxy if url form is a hard requirement, it will drive up your App Engine machine time costs though

Comment: I think the best way to serve images is using [get_serving_url()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/#using_if_lang_is_java_getservingurl_endif_if_lang_is_python_get_serving_url_endif) which will give you `https://lhx.ggpht.com/randomStringImageId` and as a bonus you can dynamically resize them. I wouldn't bother with the domain name.